# How to check bearer token is same with token sanctum in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum in my project. for request login, I using Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true) and create token with sanctum,

when i to try request data user with false Bearer token (and empty bearer token), I still get the data, event I delete field in table personal_access_token, so how I can check if the bearer token is same with token in personal_access_tokens?

Comment: you might not set the middleware on that route.